# How does Lambda within subnet access VPC endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, vpc-endpoint

I have a lambda function within a VPC that rotates rds password.
When I test lambda function with secret manager vpc endpoint as following:

- Case 1. Lambda in **public subnet** - VPC endpoint attach with **public subnet** => Rotation is OK
- Case 2. Lambda in **private subnet** - VPC endpoint attach with **public subnet** => Rotation is OK although cloudwatch has one error.
- Case 3. Lambda in **public subnet** - VPC endpoint attach with **private subnet** => Rotation is failed because timeout of lambda function
- Case 4. Lambda in **private subnet** - VPC endpoint attach with **private subnet** => Rotation is OK

I know I should not put the lambda function into public subnet but I want to know how lambda function within subnet works with vpc endpoint.

Can anyone explains why **Case 2** is OK although lambda and vpc endpoint are in different subnets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why Case 2 is OK

[VPC interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html) have **vpc scope**, not subnet scope. This explains why cases 2,1 and 4 work. Because of that, case 3 should also work. Thus, the question is why case 3 did not work?

Possible reasons are that in your tests you made some configuration mistake (wrong security group, for example), or put lambda in a wrong VPC, did not enable Private DNS for the endpoint. Thus I would recommend double checking all the configurations for Case 3 and re-run the experiment.

Comment: You are right. In Case 3, the request from lambda in public subnet -> lambda SG Outbound -> public subnet's NACL outbound -> private subnet's NACL inbound (my problem occurs here because I didn't add https 443 from source CIDR of my VPC) -> ENI attached to VPC endpoint.
Thank you.